# Create video with encoded frames in Java

Tags: java, android, video, frames

I have one application in Android (Java) that encodes frames that comes from a Camera.

Each frame is one array of bytes, that after being captured, was encoded with the API MediaCodec.

If i write the frames directly on a video file, i can open it with ffplay (not with another videoplayers as VLC), but it says for example:

```
Input #0, h263, from 'example.avi':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: h263, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 12:11 DAR 16:11], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 29.97 tbc
5.58 A-V:  0.000 s:0.0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   0/0
```

In other words, it doesnt recognise the duration, neither the bitrate.

I suppose that i have to write the metadata to the file but i have no idea how to do it.

As i said in the post, the application is being implemented with Java (with Android API), so i want to know how to add the metadata that makes the video players will recognice my video.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `MediaCodec` is a raw H.264 stream.  Starting with Android 4.3 (API 18), you can convert this stream to a .mp4 file by running it through the [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) class.

A related item, possibly of interest, is that you can now feed the camera's Surface preview to `MediaCodec` instead of passing YUV data through ByteBuffer.  This approach requires less data copying and doesn't need a color plane swap.

See the CameraToMpegTest example [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not an avi container, it is just h264 stream. Try to rename to "*.h264" and play with some player(vlc, mplayer).

Comment: Does ffplay show the video?.. Are you sure that you writes buffer correctly? Could you provide source of the way you write the buffers to file?..